# Can this find/replace be done with a single regular expression?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I can currently accomplish what I am trying to do by doing several find/replaces in notepad++, but I was wondering if I could make this more efficient by using regular expressions. Preferably a single find regex and a single replace regex. I am new to regex, so I was unsure how to even begin this.

Here is what I currently do,

Find:`Sequence:\s`

Replace with:`Seq\t\tName\t\t\t\tDescription\t\t\t\tAction\t\tEnabled\n`

Then

Find:`BR\sName:\s`

Replace with:`\t`

And similarly for each "type", Sequence, BR Name, BR Description, BR Action, and Enabled.

Here is an example of the text that I am editing:

```
Sequence: 40    BR Name: ROUTE PARTIAL  BR Description: ROUTE PARTIAL   BR Action: AFTER ROUTE  Enabled: Y
```

This is what it looks like after it has been edited:

```
Seq     Name                Description             Action      Enabled
40      ROUTE PARTIAL       ROUTE PARTIAL           AFTER ROUTE Y
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Does this work good enough..? [***Demo***](http://regex101.com/r/qF3vJ3)

Comment: @Sam Wow, that works great! I only edited it a little bit. Here is what it is after my changes, [Edited Regex](http://regex101.com/r/aF7rS9) - Sam, could you post your answer so that I can accept your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/703229/sam)'s link above:

- Regular expression:

  ```
  ^([^\s:]+):\s(.*?)\s+BR\s([^\s:]+):\s(.*?)\s+BR\s([^\s:]+):\s(.*?)\s+BR\s([^\s:]+):\s(.*?)\s+([^\s:]+):\s.*?$
  ```
- Substitution:

  ```
  \1\t\t\3\t\t\t\t\5\t\t\t\t\7\t\t\9\n\2\t\t\t\4\t\t\t\6\t\t\t\t\8\t10
  ```